# Is there a way to use Guice initialization graph in a custom provider instead of me constructing the implementations myself

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Guice with Java.

I want to change the implementation of an interface depends on the entry point to my code (which main class)

I thought to set different System.property in each entry point

and create new provider to init one of the implementations.

Is there a way to use Guice initialization graph instead of me constructing the implementations myself?

```
public class AltsMatcherProvider implements Provider<IAltsPairsMatcher> {

    @Override
    public IAltsPairsMatcher get() {

        switch (System.getProperty(regressionType)) {
            default:
            case "regular": {
                return  new AltsPairsMatcherByName();
            }
            case "bidi": {
                return  new AltsPairsMatcherBySegments();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way to do that is to inject `Provider`s of the specific implementations into the `Provider` of the generic interface:

```
public class AltsMatcherProvider implements Provider<IAltsPairsMatcher> {

    @Inject Provider<AltsPairsMatcherByName> regularProvider;
    @Inject Provider<AltsPairsMatcherBySegments> bidiProvider;

    @Override
    public IAltsPairsMatcher get() {

        switch (System.getProperty(regressionType)) {
            default:
            case "regular": {
                return regularProvider.get();
            }
            case "bidi": {
                return bidiProvider.get();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Or use constructor injection instead of `@Inject`ed fields; I'm answering from a mobile device so went for the smallest bit of code)

Answer (score 0):

I used `@Inject` in the provider

```
@Inject
public AltsMatcherProvider(ListUtils listUtils, SegmentsIdsChecker segmentsIdsChecker) {
    this.listUtils = listUtils;
    this.segmentsIdsChecker = segmentsIdsChecker;
}
@Override
public IAltsPairsMatcher get() {

    final String routingType = System.getProperty(Constants.routingType);
    if (routingType == null)
    {
        return new AltsPairsMatcherByName(listUtils, segmentsIdsChecker);
    }
    switch (routingType) {
        default:
        case "regular": {
            return  new AltsPairsMatcherByName(listUtils, segmentsIdsChecker);
        }
        case "bidi": {
            return  new AltsPairsMatcherBySegments(listUtils, segmentsIdsChecker);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Providers are injected into when they are created so you could ask for the `Injector` or `Provider`s of types `AltsPairsMatcherByName` and `AltsPairsMatcherBySegments`.

However... I'm not convinced that a custom `Provider` is the right way to go with this. This sounds to me like either a case for [custom annotations/@Named](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) OR a variant on the [Robot Legs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects).

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this I would implement two separate modules:

```
public void configure() {
    bind(IAltsPairsMatcher.class).to(AltsPairsMatcherByName.class);
}
...
public void configure() {
    bind(IAltsPairsMatcher.class).to(AltsPairsMatcherBySegments.class);
}
```

Then pick which module to install based on a system property or command line flag:

```
class ParentModule {
  public void configure() {
    switch (System.getProperty(Constants.routingType)) {
      case NAME:
        install(new ByNameModule());
        break;
      case SEGMENT:
        install(new BySegmentsModule());
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This maintains the nice property that your object graph can be resolved statically-with-respect-to the injector, and definitely won't change at runtime. Simply by examining your modules, you should be able to tell where a particular implementation came from. This is encoded in the Guice error message idiom, which shows you a chain of modules from the original parent all the way to the binding. You can also just inline the bindings in the switch statement, the important thing is that everything be resolved at injector creation time.